# vb.net Get text after before 2 character and use it

Tags: vb.net

can someone help me how can I use the datas?

```
Dim String as String = "thing=lol1 thing=lol2 thing=lol3 ..."
```

I want to use this datas somehow like this:

```
For i As Integer
Dim webClient1 As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient1.DownloadString("http://pr2hub.com/submit_rating.php?level_id=" + lol1)
Next
```

and the next is

```
Dim result As String = webClient1.DownloadString("http://pr2hub.com/submit_rating.php?level_id=" + lol2)
```

then

```
Dim result As String = webClient1.DownloadString("http://pr2hub.com/submit_rating.php?level_id=" + lol3)
```

So how can I use the datas between "=" and " "?

Comment: `Dim String as String` is not valid VB code and wont compile.  Otherwise look at String.Split to parse the string, though why glue it together if you need it as elements?

Comment: @Plutonix doesn't the parser handle it by converting it to Dim [String] As String? Its a bad idea to name a variable same as the type nevertheless :)

Comment: @MrPaulch I typed it into VS2012, because I thought it might do that or maybe replace `String` as when you create a var named `System`.  That would mean he/she could not use `String.Split` because they replaced the type.  VS2012 would not accept it.  typing it as `[String]` works (but still a very bad idea), but that is not in the OP.

Comment: Ok i checked, too. VB does replace a variable name matching a class name with the [...] substitute. But VB complains if you use one of it's own Keywords... (Quiet inconsistant i think). So: `Dim Int32 As Int32` will work, but `Dim Integer as Integer` wont :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you have a string containing key/value pairs separated by spaces. You could use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to extract the necessary information:

```
Dim result as String = "thing=lol1 thing=lol2 thing=lol3 ..."
Dim tokens = result.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
For Each token As String In tokens
    Dim kvp = token.Split(New String() {"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If kvp.Length > 1 Then
        Dim key as String = kvp(0)
        Dim value as String = kvp(1)
        ' Do something with the key and value here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I wish I could type faster :(